# PyQt Multithreaded program based on QRunnable is not working properly

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

In this small `PyQt` based program, I have created a counter that counts from 0 to 10, in 10 seconds. While I use `QRunnable` to run counter in `countBox()` in a separate thread but after pressing start button GUI becomes not responding and counter does not work at all. Do you have any idea about what's wrong with this? Thanks.

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QGridLayout, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QLineEdit, QPushButton, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRunnable, pyqtSlot, QThreadPool

import time, sys

class Worker(QRunnable):
    def __init__(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        self.fn = fn
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)

def createCounterWorker():
    threadpool = QThreadPool()
    worker = Worker(countBox)
    threadpool.start(worker)

def countBox():
    i = 0
    while i < 10:
        print(f'i: {i}')
        time.sleep(1.0)
        i += 1

class Counter():
    def __init__(self, layout):
        self.startButton = QPushButton(f'Start')
        self.startButton.pressed.connect(lambda: createCounterWorker())
        layout.addWidget(self.startButton)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.btn = QPushButton('+')
        self.btn.pressed.connect(lambda: self.addNewCounter())
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn)

        w = QWidget()
        w.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(w)
        self.show()

    def addNewCounter(self):
        newCount = Counter(self.layout)

app = QApplication([])
window = MainWindow()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is simple: threadpool is the object that creates the threads, it is a local variable that will be destroyed instantly along with the threads, so countBox will be executed in the main thread, causing the GUI to freeze, so the solution is to extend the life cycle of that variable so there are the following options:

- Make threadpool a global variable:

  ```
  threadpool = QThreadPool()

  def createCounterWorker():
      worker = Worker(countBox)
      threadpool.start(worker)
  ```
- Use QThreadPool.globalInstance():

  ```
  def createCounterWorker():
      worker = Worker(countBox)
      QThreadPool.globalInstance().start(worker)
  ```

Comment: Thanks! Your answer really helped me.